# Field blogCategoryid doesn't have a default value coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion-11

I need help resolving this default issue, please.  I am working with the learncfinaweek.com tutorials in the ORM section.http://www.learncfinaweek.com/week1/Intro_to_ORM/

The category section was adding fields before I deleted some of db data from the blogposts because of a different error, which got resolved and I can add blogposts now, but the category section for those are not adding categories now and give this Field blogCategoryid doesn't have a default value.

There are two tables in the db with blogCategoryid, blogcategory and blogpostcategory.  Their are three component cfc pages that are suppose to connect the blogposts to the categories.

Please help me on how to proceed to resolve this, or at least what code to put on here to help others help me.  Or is it simply the database tables?

Answer (score 0):

I got it working!  Simply open up MYSQL Workbench, highlight and rightclick on all the tables and choose DROP.  Then run the import_mysql that is available from the learncfinaweek downloads.  Code is good and so are the tables now.  The site is working great.